# Avoiding code duplication -- best approach

Tags: java, design-patterns

I've got two methods with the same list and types of arguments and almost the same body but each of them calls another function to fetch list of elements. To be more precise:

```
    public void method1 (int a, int b) {
            //body (the same in both of methods)
            List<SomeObject> list = service.getListA(int c, int d);
            //rest of the body (the same in both of methods)
        }

        public void method2 (int a, int b) {
            //body (the same in both of methods)
            List<SomeObject> list = service.getListB(int c, int d, int e);
            //rest of the body (the same in both of methods)
        }
```

What is the best approach to the problem avoiding code duplication in that case? I thought about Strategy pattern, but there is a problem with difference in argument list.

UPDATE:

```
    public void method1 (int a, int b) {
            //body (the same in both of methods)
            int c = some_value;
            List<SomeObject> list = service.getListA(a, b, c);
            //rest of the body (the same in both of methods)
        }

        public void method2 (int a, int b) {
            //body (the same in both of methods)
            int c = some_value;
            int d = another_value;
            List<SomeObject> list = service.getListB(a, b, c, d);
            //rest of the body (the same in both of methods)
        }
```

So some variables are local and some are passed through arguments.

Comment: Pass you `List<SomeObject>` as an argument to a single function and wrap it?

Comment: Are c, d, and e fields or are they local variables in these methods?

Comment: Can you rewrite your example so it compiles or at least uses the right syntax?

Comment: I would like to reiterate @DonRoby s question about c,d,e being locally generated (inside the method) or global/externally generated. It matters A LOT to the question

Answer (score 6):

Factor them out into additional methods.

```
public void method1 (int a, int b) {
        MyClass myClass = method3(a, b);
        List<SomeObject> list = service.getListA(myClass.getC(), myClass.getD());
        method4(list);
}

public void method2 (int a, int b) {
        MyClass myClass = method3(a, b);
        List<SomeObject> list = service.getListB(myClass.getC(), myClass.getD(), myClass.getE());
        method4(list);
}

public MyClass {
    private final int c;
    private final int d;
    private final int e;
    ...
}

public MyClass method3(int a, int b) {
    // body
    return new MyClass(c, d, e)
}

public void method4(List<SomeObject> list) {
    // rest of body
}
```

Comment: There will still be code duplication, invoking the two methods this way is a code duplication itself... I think the OP is after a design pattern approach.

Comment: @amit I agree, however more OO methods would require even more lines of code then the small amount of duplication above. Even using a case statement introduces the same number of lines... Of course, it depends on the use case, as an OO approach may be more extensible in the future.

Comment: @dicarlo2: with that approach you need a new method for every case. With the approach in my answer, you could also put the list-selection code inside the enum and get rid of the `switch` statement. That means, further possibilities only have to be added in the enum, and code duplication would be eliminated completely.

Comment: @jlordo I don't disagree, however I think it is definitely case dependent, sometimes it would be better to just factor it out into additional methods, sometimes it would be better to use a case/enum approach, sometimes it would be better to use a more OO approach.

Answer (score 4):

One way of avoiding code duplication in your case could be to introduce an extra parameter that is used to decide which method to retrieve the list is going to be used:

```
public void method (int a, int b, int method) {
    //body (the same in both of methods)
    List<SomeObject> list = null;
    switch (method) {
        case 1: 
            list = service.getListA(int c, int d);
            break;
        case 2: 
            list = service.getListB(int c, int d, int e);
            break;
    }
    //rest of the body (the same in both of methods)
}
```

instead of using `int method` as the additional parameter I would use an new `enum` type and define a `default` case in the `switch` statement.

Comment: +1 Clean and code duplication free. Just please replace the `int method` to an enum, for making it even better.

Comment: @amit: see my edit, wanted to push out the code and then write my comment ;)

Comment: Then how about including the "method fetching" part in the enum to get rid of the switch?

Comment: -1 Every time you want to get a list using a different method signature you have to modify this code. You are better sending in the list as a parameter

Comment: +1, although I agree with @assylias, that's probably the best approach. (Strategy enum pattern).

Comment: @PaulSullivan: Sending the list as a paremeter is most likely impossible, assuming the arguments `c,d,e` are unknown before the first common code.

Comment: @assylias: would that be possible, if `c`, `d` and `e` are calculated after the enum was passed to the method?

Comment: Why not? Just include what is in your case in a method within the enum and call `THE_ENUM.theMethod(c, d, e);` - that assumes that c and d are always the first 2 arguments.

Comment: @amit There is no indication in the question if the variables c,d,e are local or global. If they are global (produced outside the method then the list can be passed in... This can also be done using interfaces and possibly by simulation of delegates (java seems to lack a lot of support but can be done after a cursory scan)

Comment: @assylias: good point. Would lead to cleaner code. Thanks for pointing it out ;)

Comment: @PaulSullivan (1) global variable? in java? I guess you mean *instance variable* (or *class variables*?). (2) Even if they are *instance variables* - if they are modified in the first common code - this approach is impossible to be done. (3) Well, it is not written - but the general convention around seems to be it is the case that these variables are changed in the common code - which makes the problem interesting.

Comment: @amit assumption is the mother of all evils. Until the OP clarifies the origin of c,d,e, we can't categorically answer the question

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulate the invocation of service.getListA or service.getListB in an ListSource class/interface, implement each version in concrete classes and pass a concrete instance as a third argument. This is basically the object-oriented version of the answer proposed by jlordo.

```
interface ListSource {
    List<SomeObject> getList(int c, int d, int e);
}

class ListSourceA implements ListSource {
    // constructor etc.
    @Override
    public getList(int c, int d, int e) {
      return service.getListB(c, d);
    }
}

class ListSourceB implements ListSource {
    // constructor etc.
    @Override
    public getList(int c, int d, int e) {
      return service.getListA(c, d, e);
    }
}

public void method (int a, int b, ListSource source) {
    //body (the same in both of methods)
    List<SomeObject> list = source.getList(int c, int d, int e);
    //rest of the body (the same in both of methods)
}
```

Comment: Or `List<SomeObject> getList(int... args);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void method (int a, int b, List<SomeObject> theList) {
    //body (the same in both of methods)
    List<SomeObject> list = theList;
    //rest of the body (the same in both of methods)
}
```

This to me removes ALL the code duplication, means the method NEVER has to be modified each time we want to operate on a list derived using a different method signature.

I believe you could further this if the type SomeObject is not known using generics i.e. (and I am not a java programmer so you will have to [read the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html))

```
public void method (int a, int b, List<T> theList) {
    //body (the same in both of methods)
    List<T> list = theList;
    //rest of the body (the same in both of methods)
}
```

Comment: where has to OP stated the variables c,d,e are locally derived? @assylias

Comment: @PaulSullivan It's implied by the fact that they aren't part of the argument list to the methods.

Comment: Admittedly he hasn't. But that would make little sense to ask in that case. It is worth clarifying.

Comment: @dicarlo2 Not true... could be part of the class, private, protected, static, public....

Comment: @PaulSullivan True, I'd be fairly surprised if that were the case, however.

Comment: @dicarlo2 You would be suprised if a programmer accessed class variables directly from within a method...

Comment: @dicarlo2 you and I may encapsulate but I have seen the work of 'professional' external developers and this is the least of the code smell

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an enum:

```
public void method(int a, int b, Service service) {
    // body
    List<SomeObject> list = service.getList(myClass);
    // rest
}

public enum Service {
    METHOD_1 {
        @Override
        public List<SomeObject> getList(MyClass myClass) {}
    },
    METHOD_2 {
        @Override
        public List<SomeObject> getList(MyClass myClass) {}
    };

    public abstract List<SomeObject> getList(MyClass myClass);
}

public MyClass {
    private final int c;
    private final int d;
    private final int e;
    ...
}
```

Essentially the same as @proskor except in a different form.

Comment: return type `void` for `getList()`? Also, I would get rid of `MyClass` and would use `int...` as paramter for the method.

Comment: @jlordo Fixed, also using an additional class shields the `getList` method from further changes. Say you needed to add a `double` later to some `METHOD_5`, it would require one extra field in `MyClass` and minimal change to the original method, rather than changing every `getList`.

Answer (score -1):

If the body parts depend upon one another so you can't do as @dicarlo2's answer:

```
private interface GetObjects {
    List<SomeObject> get();
}

public void method1(int a, int b) {
    impl(a, b, new GetObjects() { public List<SomeObject> get() {
        return service.getListA(c, d);
    }});
}

public void method2(int a, int b) {
    impl(a, b, new GetObjects() { public List<SomeObject> get() {
        return service.getListB(c, d, e);
    }});
}

private void impl(int a, int b, GetObjects getObjects) {
    //body (the same in both of methods)
    List<SomeObject> list = getObjects.get();
    //rest of the body (the same in both of methods)
}
```

You can use an enum in place of `GetObjects` if you are concerned about the `new`, but don't mind getting the order mixed up, missing out on outer `this` and don't want to open this up (although it could implement an public interface).

Better syntax coming in Java SE 8, possibly. IIRC, along the lines of:

```
public void method1(int a, int b) {
    impl(a, b, { -> service.getListA(c, d) });
}
```

Comment: Where do `c`, `d`, and `e` come from?

Comment: @dicarlo2 I assumed they were fields. If they're locals, then you have choices: add more params, introduce a new (hopefully interesting) object, etc.

Comment: Under that assumption it looks a bit over complicated vs. simply passing the list as an argument...